# Erro ao incluir js na view

Tags: javascript, html, include

No sistema que eu estou trabalhando, existe um arquivo php de funções js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function alertaProximaBloqueada(){
    [...]
  }
  function ManualAluno() {
    [...]
  }
  [...]
</script>
```

Esse arquivo é incluido no final da view que utiliza essas funções, assim:

```
</body>
<?php include 'Includes/funcoes_ameai.php';?>
```

O que acontece é que quando olho no código fonte com o crtl+u as funções estão todas lá, mas quando tento executar qualquer uma, recebo esse erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: NOME_DA_FUNCAO is not defined
>   [...]

O mais estranho, é que se eu copiar a função e jogar no mesmo lugar que ela está sendo incluida, dentro da view (entre as tags ), consigo executa-la normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está chamando as funções no meio da view enquanto que elas estão sendo declaradas após o `body` em outro bloco `<script>`. Com isso, ao tentar executar as funções antes, elas ainda não foram carregadas na memória.

Você pode resolver isso esperando o DOM ser carregado, chamando as funções dentro do evento `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   // chame as funções aqui
});
</script>
```

**Exemplo com erro:**

```html
<script>
funcao();
</script>

<script>
function funcao(){
   console.log("ok");
}
</script>
```

**Exemplo sem erro:**

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   funcao();
});
</script>

<script>
function funcao(){
   console.log("ok");
}
</script>
```

Você poderia resolver isso também carregando as funções no `<head>` ou no início no `<body>`, sem a necessidade de usar `DOMContentLoaded`.

Outra ponto a ver é que se você estiver chamando funções usando triggers a partir do elemento, como `onclick`, por exemplo, ao usar a função do evento `DOMContentLoaded` irá resultar no mesmo erro, porque as funções estão no escopo do `DOMContentLoaded`. Se for esse o caso, você tem 2 alternativas: carregar as funções no `head` ou início do `body` (aí não precisa usar `DOMContentLoaded`), ou trocar `onclick` por `addEventListener` ou `element.onclick`, onde `element` é o elemento que dispara a função.

Answer (score 1):

Transforme o arquivo **funcoes_ameai.php** em um arquivo **funcoes_ameai.js** e o chame na view da seguinte forma:

```
<script src="/Includes/funcoes_ameai.js"></script>
```

A diferença entre o arquivo `.php` e o `.js` para suas funções é que você pode retirar as tags `<script>` do inicio e do fim do arquivo `.php` e programar no arquivo todo em linguagem `.js`

Comment: Eu já havia tentado isso, vou tentar mais uma vez

Comment: Não funcionou mesmo, ele importa, se eu acessar ele no código fonte, consigo visualizar o código e mesmo assim o erro se repete

Comment: Ao ver o código fonte, o script está sendo chamado antes do local onde a função dele é chamada? O que eu quero dizer é que, se durante a execução, você tentar chamar uma função js que será declarada após, realmente não irá funcionar.